# find the minimum sum of element in a matrix such that column should be consecutive during addition

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic-programming, memoization

I would actually want to get minimum sum from the matrix so that element chosen from the matrix such that column should be consecutive and element should not choose from old row if any new row is chosen.
for example if addition is `arr[0][0] + arr[1][1] + arr[0][2] as arr[0][2]` should not be there as we change the row in second addition of matrix. example-:

```
1 9 1
2 0 3 
1 7 3
```

so in above `arr[0][0] + arr[1][1] +arr[0][1] =1 + 0 + 1 = 2` gives min sum but this is not accepted sum should be `arr[0][0] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][2] = 1 +0 + 3 = 4` is accepted.no matter all row element is chosen or not only element from each column should be chosen and no element should be same column or the previous column only consecutive column addition is accepted
input -:

```
3 3
1 2 2 
2 1 2
3 2 1 

output -: arr[0][0] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][2] = 3

input -:
3 3
1 2 2 
2 5 2
3 2 2

output -: arr[0][0] + arr[0][1] + arr[0][2] = 5

input -:
3 3
1 2 2 
2 5 2
1 1 1

output -: arr[2][0] +arr[2][1] + arr[2][2]


the above test case runs fine but my code fails for some test cases

input -:
3 3
1 2 3 
1 2 3
0 3 1

expected output -: 4 
my output -: 3

4 2
2 2 2 2
1 2 3 4

expected output -: 8
my output -: 3
```

**My code**

```
# cook your dish here

import math
def mincost(matrix,initial_row,initial_col,prevcol,col,row):
    if initial_row == row or initial_col == col:
        return 0
  
    dp = [[math.inf for x in range(col+1)] for y in range(row)]
    if dp[initial_row][prevcol+1] != math.inf:
        return dp[initial_row][prevcol+1]
    res = math.inf
    for i in range(row):
        if initial_col != prevcol:
            val = matrix[i][initial_col] + mincost(matrix,i,initial_col+1,initial_col,row,col)
            res = min(res,val)
        dp[i][prevcol+1] = res  
    return res

# main fuction    
col,row = input( ).split( )
row = int(row)
col = int(col)
matrix=[ ]
for i in range(row):
    row_list=[int(x) for x in input( ).split( )]
    matrix.append(row_list)

#sending perivious column as -1 to backtrack the element should not from previous column 
result = mincost(matrix,0,0,-1,col,row)
print(result)
```

Comment: A couple of hints: 1) Don't use single-letter variable names, especially if you want other people to understand your code. 2) Start programming the function without memoization and make it work first. 3) Define what your function is supposed to return and what the inputs mean. Document this as comments. Also, comment each step of your algorithm. This will probably show you some inconsistencies. At least, it will give others the chance to find things that are not doing what you think they are.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks for the suggestion but I already asked the above question with test cases I just call it recursively the minimum element column wise and question is cleared my code is just for help single-letter are just rows and columns in a matrix and rest is already named variables

Comment: Personally, I find a few things in the code a bit confusing. That's why I asked you to define the functionality of the function. E.g., why is there `col` and `prevcol`? It seems to me that always `col = prevcol + 1`. How can `row == n` happen? You named your iteration variable `row`, which hides the function parameter `row`. Is this intended? Why is `mincost(arr,0,0,-1,p,d)` the result? This all depends on the meaning of the function. I have a feeling of what you intended, but I want you to confirm that feeling.

Comment: @NicoSchertler prevcol is just to take care element should not from previous visited column and i have edit the code you can look into it

Comment: People have been posting this question with different descriptions over and over during the past few days. Techgig codegladiators semi final round1 techgig.com/codegladiators . The problem is active till july 6th for submissions. (An accepted solution is actually posted on SO, but not under the dynamic-programming tag.)